# SQLite Troubleshooting a missing table in R

Tags: r, sqlite

Looking to Inner join the results from one query with another in the SQLite Package in R. So far I have the following code:

```
library(SQLite)
sql<- 
   "SELECT 
      telecast.telecast_id, 
      telecast.series_name, 
      affiliates.network_name

    FROM telecast a 
    JOIN affiliates b 
      ON a.network_id = b.network_id limit 10;"

    res <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
    df_ti <- dbFetch(res)
    print(df_ti)
```

When I run the code, it says there is no table found but when I run just

```
SELECT telecast.telecast_id FROM telecast
```

The information shows up. I am not too good with troubleshooting in SQLite in R, any thoughts on how to fix this??

Comment: Does the table `affiliates` exist in your database? What if you run a basic select query on that table?

Comment: The affiliates table does exist in the database, which is why it doesn't make sense when I try to combine them

Comment: Try changing the table names in the SELECT query, as you are creating aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You create aliasses for your tables.
If you change your select query to use these, I had it working.

```
library(SQLite)
sql<- 
   "SELECT 
      a.telecast_id, 
      a.series_name, 
      b.network_name

    FROM telecast a 
    JOIN affiliates b 
      ON a.network_id = b.network_id limit 10;"

    res <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
    df_ti <- dbFetch(res)
    print(df_ti)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Your suggestion of creating aliases for the tables was spot on. I just declared each table an alias using AS. The code I was able to come up with is below, thanks for the help!

```
SELECT 
    t.series_name,
    ti.num_views_per_telecast
FROM
(SELECT 
ti.telecast_id,
ti.network_id,
count(*) as num_views_per_telecast
FROM
tunein AS ti
INNER JOIN
affiliates AS a
ON
ti.network_id = a.network_id
WHERE
ti.dvr_time_shift = 'L+SD' and 
a.network_name = 'ABC'
group by
ti.telecast_id,
ti.network_id
)ti
inner join telecast AS t
On 
t.telecast_id = ti.telecast_id
ORDER BY ti.num_views_per_telecast DESC
```